# Continuous mapping from open set to open set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have two open and bounded sets, $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a continuous function $\textbf{f}$ mapping $\Omega_1$ onto $\Omega_2$?

\begin{align*}
\Omega_1 & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < x^2 + y^2 <2 \} \\
\Omega_2 & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 3x^2 < x^2 + y^2 < 4\}
\end{align*}

I'm having trouble applying the definition of onto, i.e. for all $\textbf{y}$ in $\Omega_2$, there is AT LEAST ONE $\text{x} \in \Omega_1$ such that $\textbf{f}(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{y}$. Or I need to show that 
$$\textbf{f}(\Omega_1) = \Omega_2$$

Comment: How does your comment about compact sets answer the question?  A subset $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.  For $\Omega_1$ to be compact, it would have to be both closed and open, but also a strict subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as it is bounded, which is a contradiction as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

Comment: I dun know how to answer this question - any hint is appreciated thanks

Comment: Well, if you do not require $f$ to be injective, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I'm having trouble following your logic. If $\textbf{f}$ is injective, then for all $\textbf{y} \in \Omega_2$, there is at most $1$ $\textbf{x} \in \Omega_1$ such that $\textbf{f}(\textbf{x}) =\textbf{y}$. I'm failing to see why this is not the case for this question

Comment: I was writing an answer, but while I was thinking about it I realised I was probably wrong.

Comment: Actually, I was *outrageously* wrong!

Comment: *Hint*: $\Omega_2$ is not connected.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Hm, made a huge mistake drawing $\Omega_2$. Thanks, I geddit! Do you have tips for drawing these? I split them into two inequalities and then sketch

Also, your thoughts on injectivity sparked a thought, is $\textbf{f}^{-1}$ injective and/or onto?

Comment: $\Omega_2$ is not open though: it includes the origin but not $(\varepsilon,0)$ for any $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Uzman: $\Omega_2$ does not include the origin since the inequalities are strict.

Comment: @Jose27 Right, thanks!

Comment: Why would we even consider ontoness? Sassatelli's remark is sufficient, no?

Comment: @Uzman I don't see why $f^{-1}$ is onto. It would be easy to see it if $K_2$ is path-connected, then $f^{-1}(K_2) = K_1$ is path-connected. So by truth tables, $F \rightarrow T$ is true so.. the conclusion to the implication is true even if the assumption is false, i.e. $K$ is not path-connected. 

So the following statement is true: if $K$ is not path-connected, then $f^{-1}(K) = L$ is path-connected?

Comment: Oh, we use the ontoness to consider $\Omega_2$ as the image of $\Omega_1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Omega_2 $ is not connected but the set $\Omega_1 $ is connected. Since the image by the continiuous function  of connected set is always connected thus such function does not exist.

Comment: $\Omega_2$ is connected.

Comment: Points $A=(0,1) $ and $B=(0,-1)$ are elements of the set $\Omega_2 $ but there is no point of the form $C_x =(x,0 ) $ in $\Omega_2 .$ Hence the set $\Omega_2 $ is not connected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong. I interpreted $\Omega_2$ $\{\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :  x^2 + y^2 < 4 \text{ and } y \ge 3 x^2\}$ which is not the case.

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx That was my original mistake aswell

Answer (score 1):

**My hint here is wrong.**

I was having in mind that $\Omega_2$ was equal to $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 2 \text{ and } 3 x^2 \le y\}$ which is not the case. I however don't delete the answer as it is interesting to find a continuous mapping between $\Omega_1$ onto $\Omega_2^\prime=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 2 \text{ and } 3 x^2 \le y\}$.

You have $\Omega_1= \Omega_1^i \uplus \Omega_1^e$ where:

\begin{align*}
\Omega_1^i & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < x^2 + y^2 \le 3/2 \} \\
\Omega_1^e & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 3/2 < x^2 + y^2 < 2 \}
\end{align*}

The disk $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + (y-1)^2 \le 1/4 \}$ is included in $\Omega_2$. *To be verified precisely. If this is not true, a disk centered on $(0,1)$ with a radius small enough is included in $\Omega_1$ as $\Omega_1$ is open and $(0,1) \in \Omega_1$.*

Now you can find

- $g$ continuous from $\Omega_1^i$ onto $D$.
- $h$ continuous from $\Omega_1^e$ onto $\Omega_2^\prime \setminus D$

in such a way that $f$ defined by
\begin{align*}
f|\Omega_1^i = g \\
f|\Omega_1^e = h
\end{align*}

is continuous.