# Continuous map from a connected open subset of the plane onto another one

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ be two non empty open connected subsets of the plane. Is it always possible to find a continuous map $f$ from $\Omega_1$ onto $\Omega_2$?

*Note: The origin of my question is this one: [continuous-mapping-from-open-set-to-open-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319493/continuous-mapping-from-open-set-to-open-set/1319606#1319606).*

Comment: Someone needs to answer this so I can go to sleep.

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh I took the OP to mean open sets as in the title.

Comment: @Tim. Same for me Tim. I'm based in France... It's almost noon so I still have some time in front of me! What about you?

Comment: @David Mitra Subsets are supposed to be open. Do you in fact mean bounded?

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the post body.

Comment: I should be more precise. I modified the post body.

Comment: Gosh, good question. If they are simply connected, the answer is yes, because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem)..

Comment: Might be overkill, but doesn't {the existence of space filling curves} + {the fact that every open set is a countable union of closed squares} give it to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, this is probably overkill, but if we use space-filling curves, we can take for granted that there exists a continuous surjection $[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Now if $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open, connected, there exists a continuous surjection $V\rightarrow (0,1)$ (for instance, just project to the x-axis to get a disjoint union of open intervals, then choose one such interval $J$, take the identity on $J$ and send all the others into $J$)

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, connected, and write $$U:=\cup_{i=1}^\infty C_i$$ where $C_i$ are a countable collection of closed squares (of varying sizes).

We can define a surjective map $f_1:[1/2, 1)\rightarrow C_1$ and a path $\gamma :[1/3,1/2]\rightarrow  U$ with $\gamma(1/2)= f(1/2), \gamma (1/3)\in C_2$. Now define a surjective map $f_2: [1/4,1/3] \rightarrow C_2$. concatenating these maps gives a surjective map $[1/4,1)\rightarrow C_1\cup C_2$. Continuing in this way gives a surjection $(0,1) \rightarrow V$.

....right?

Actually it seems silly to use space filling curves because we collapsed space just to fill it again. You could replace $(0,1)$ with an open strip, which you think of as a divided into squares, mapping the first square to $C_1$, the next square to $\gamma$, the next square to $C_2$...

Comment: It seems to be OK.

Comment: I like the idea. One thing is not clear however. How do you ensure that your map from $(0,1)$ to $U$ is continuous? It is for sure continuous on each interval $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$. What about the continuity at points $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: So we have maps $[1/4,1/3]\rightarrow U, [1/3,1/2]\rightarrow U, [1/2,1]\rightarrow U$ which are all continuous and agree at 1/3 and 1/2. Then we can paste them together to get a continuous map.  I think this is called the "pasting lemma." Does that clarify?

Comment: It does. Great answer and idea. Thanks.